# KDE intermittent wifi problem "configuring interface"

Tags: wireless, kde

I have 20.04 kubuntu.
I have my own wifi hotspot from my telephone as my main connection.  Hidden and pwd protected.

Every so often my kde wifi connection does not connect and says.. "configuring interface"
I try this and then and then reboot and all is fine and connected.

This happened yesterday with another wifi connection also.

Comment: Did you do anything that you think might be causing the problem? If so, let me know.

Comment: I don't think I did anything.  It is a hidden WiFi hotspot.  If I reboot it usually does the problem.  I think it might be related to turning on the WiFi hotspot as it is booting.  However it does this with another hotspot too.  I might place a bug with network manager.

Comment: You aren't running on a laptop are you?

Comment: Then I don't know what to say.

Comment: yes.  it is acer swift 3, from 2019 i5 8gb ram

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem as yours, but with my router's wifi network. It was stuck at "configuring interface".

Somehow, these below commands solved my problem.

```bash
sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant.service

sudo systemctl mask wpa_supplicant.service
```

Now **Reboot** your computer and run.

```bash
sudo systemctl unmask wpa_supplicant.service

sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant.service
```

Comment: I switched to Pure Ubuntu.  Does not happen.  I like stuff that works rather than what is more fun to work with.